# How to limit the number of Jobs running in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have few folders in which my script runs and triggers job for each folder. Imagine if I have 10 subfolders inside the main folder and I want to limit the number of jobs running to at a time to be 5. how can I do that? I will put my code below.

```
function ThrottleJob([int]$MaxJob) {
    do {
        $jobs = Get-Job -state "Running"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    } while ($jobs.Count -gt $MaxJob)
}

$folders = @()
$folders += (Get-Item $path).FullName
$folders += Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory 
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    if (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder) {
        ThrottleJob -MaxJob 5
        Start-Job -InitializationScript $allJobs -ScriptBlock { runJob -path $args[0]} -ArgumentList $folder | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: This can be easily accomplished using the [ThreadJob module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.2) which already has the `-ThrottleLimit` parameter. Alternatively, this can be done easily with runspace.

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon, I did tried using ThreadJob and the output wasn't correct as I got while using Start-job. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can an example for setting a threshold for `Start-Job`, I do believe a normal `foreach` loop will be faster than this.

```sh
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Management.Automation

$maxJobs = 5
$path = "$HOME\Documents"

$folders = @(
    (Get-Item $path).FullName
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory).FullName
)

$jobs = [List[Job]]::new()

foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    $job = Start-Job {
         Get-ChildItem $using:folder -File | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name
    }
    $jobs.Add($job)

    while(($jobs.State -eq 'Running').Count -ge $maxJobs)
    {
        Clear-Host
        Get-Job -State Running | Format-Table -AutoSize
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

$result = Receive-Job $jobs -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
$result | Format-Table
```

As you can see, the code is awfully complicated. This is how it would look using `Start-ThreadJob`, which will most likely be faster than a `foreach` loop and will consume less memory than `Start-Job`.

```
$maxJobs = 5
$path = "$HOME\Documents"

$folders = @(
    (Get-Item $path).FullName
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory).FullName
)

$jobs = foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    Start-ThreadJob {
        Get-ChildItem $using:folder -File | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name
    } -ThrottleLimit $maxJobs
}

$result = Receive-Job $jobs -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
$result | Format-Table
```